# the power as noun

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives

> *The power as commander* is given to the president.

I am not so sure if I can use "*as*" as the adjectival preposition as in this sentence?
 Is it grammatical?

Comment: Moderators of this community now are trying to reduce the use of the "grammar" tag, you should use a more specific tag like "noun" or 'adjective"

Comment: No. You can't use this preposition in this context, however, note this: "The power goes to the commander as the general can lead the armies no longer."

Comment: I think what you mean might be *"The power is given to the president as commander"* - that is, the power is given to the president *because of his role as* commander.  Alternately, maybe you mean *"The power of being commander is given to the president."*

Answer (score 1):

> The power as commander is given to the president.

This sounds like *commander* is describing the subject if the sentence were not passive, instead of describing the type of *power*.  I think it's technically grammatical but sounds confusing and odd.

> The power as commander is given to the president = Someone, acting as commander, gave power to the president.

If you want to say *commander* as in "kind of power", use *of* or just use *commander* as an adjective:

> The power of commander is given to the president.
>
> The commander power is given to the president.